# session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in

Tags: php, mvc, session

he leido en todos las preguntas, he intentado millones de cosas pero no logro resolver el problema de la session.
Mi aplicacion comienza con un archivo index.php que lo que hace es llamar a una vista, ahi puse un

```
<?php
session_start();
require "vista/usuario/login.php";
?>
```

En el login.php tambien vuelvo a llamar al session_start y este archivo que seria la vista, lo que hace es pedir usuario y contraseña, y enviarlo a un archivo controlador.php
En el archivo controlador.php vuelvo a iniciar la session( al comienzo del codigo), y una vez que  verifica que el usuario y la contraseña sean validos guardo esos datos, este es el codigo:

```
 public function verificarUsuario($cuit, $contrasenia)
    {
        $this->cuit= $cuit;
        $this->contrasenia =$contrasenia;
        $infoUsuario = $this->buscarUsuarioCuit();
        foreach($infoUsuario as $usuario){}
        if (password_verify($contrasenia, $usuario->contrasenia))
        {
            $_SESSION["cuit"]=$usuario->cuit;   
            $_SESSION["contrasenia"]=$usuario->contrasenia;  
            $_SESSION["nivel"] =$usuario->nivel;

            $this->redireccionarPrincipal();
        }
        else 
        {
            echo '<html><script language="javascript">alert("Contraseña incorrecta")</script><html>';
        }
```

Este archivo redirecciona a un menu.php, y ahi ni bien entro vuelvo a realizar un session_start(): y cuando quiero mostrar las variables, no tienen datos

```
<?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION)){
  session_start();
  echo "entro al star";
  echo $_SESSION["nivel"]; 
 echo $_SESSION["cuit"];  
 echo $_SESSION["contrasenia"];  
  echo "mostro variables ?";
}
 ?>
```

me muestra entro al start y mostro variables pero nada en las variables de session.
Alguien puede ayudarme, por favor?
Se los agradezco.

Comment: por que en el primer ejemplo, tienes 2 veces el session start ?? solo deberia haber uno y en php...

Comment: perdon el de arriba no va, fue un error, solo que lo iba a escribir y luego copie el codigo

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Podrías poner el mensaje de error **exacto**? ¿Podrías compartir el contenido de `login.php`, `controlador.php` y `menu.php`? Estás compartiendo solo un extracto y es posible que el error esté en otras líneas.

Comment: @kar73 en el primero haces un `require` al login, cuando el session start ya está iniciado... por eso aparece ese error.